# Query(Importrange) or Query with dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange, google-sheets-dates

I am trying to show or limit what is seen to just entries made in 2019.  I found a few places that referenced this and have tried the following without success.

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("1bSyor-91_py58oDPVfalwcSB7Fw4mmJmD1jEOTIE7FU", "FVA_2017!A:M"),"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where L > date '2019-01-01' and L < date '2019-12-30'")
```

Or to query the sheet directly from within the same file.

```
=query("FVA_2017!A:M","select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where L > date '2019-01-01' and L < date '2019-12-30'")
```

I am getting the same error

> "Unable to parse the query string for Function Query parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A"

trying both of the queries.

If I just do a regular `importrange` such as

`=IMPORTRANGE("1bSyor-91_py58oDPVfalwcSB7Fw4mmJmD1jEOTIE7FU", "FVA_2017!A:M")`

I get everything. The date column is L and the format a standard date field from a Google form 4/29/2019.  The first row is a header row would this cause an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**correct syntax:**

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1bSyor-91_py58oDPVfalwcSB7Fw4mmJmD1jEOTIE7FU", "FVA_2017!A:M"),
 "where Col12 > date '2019-01-01' 
    and Col12 < date '2019-12-30'", 0)
```

```
=QUERY(FVA_2017!A:M, "where L > date '2019-01-01' 
                        and L < date '2019-12-30'", 0)
```

```
=QUERY({FVA_2017!A:M}, "where Col12 > date '2019-01-01' 
                          and Col12 < date '2019-12-30'", 0)
```

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT("FVA_2017!A:M"), "where Col12 > date '2019-01-01' 
                                    and Col12 < date '2019-12-30'", 0)
```

Comment: What are the differences between the bottom 3 Queries?

Comment: in essence - none. the result is the same. it's just showoff of syntax differences when you use direct range (L) and indirect range (Col12) or {arrayed range} (Col12)

Answer (score 0):

Please try Importrange and query at the same time using:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Spreadsheet URL","SO!A:O"), "where Col6 <= date '"&TEXT(K1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND Col7 >= date '"&TEXT(K1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

K1 cell: You can update any date in the cell of the same sheet from where or after you need the date range condition. By doing this you can lock in the date easily.